# Populate JSON List To C# Object

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net, converters

I'm trying to populate a JSON/XML string into C# object.
I convert my XML to JSON and then use JSON.NET. Example:

**JSON string**

```
{  
"persons":[  
  {  
     "age":30,
     "name":"david",
     "hobbies":[  
        {  
           "name":"tennis",
           "hours":5
        },
        {  
           "name":"football",
           "hours":10
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "name":"adam",
     "age":23,
     "hobbies":[]
  }
]
}
```

**C# Classes**

```
public class Hobbies
{
    public string name;
    public int hours;
}

class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public List<Hobbies> hoobies = new List<Hobbies>();
}
```

I'm trying to populate the data into a list of persons:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(myJsonText, persons);
```

and I'm getting this exception:

> Cannot populate JSON object onto type

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is `JSON` representation of an Object:

```
{
  "key":"value"
}
```

and here is the representation of a collection/array/list of an Object

```
[
    {
      "key":"value"
    },
    {
      "key2":"value2"
    }
]
```

So your `JSON` string doesn't representing the array or collection of the `Person` class. It's representing the object with `Persons` property which is a collection of `Person` object.

To parse it to the `List<Person>`, remove the outermost `{` `}` and then try.

Your JSON should look like this

```
[
    {
        "age": 30,
        "name": "david",
        "hobbies": [
            {
                "name": "tennis",
                "hours": 5
            },
            {
                "name": "football",
                "hours": 10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "adam",
        "age": 23,
        "hobbies": []
    }
]
```

and then deserialize it like this

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a root object

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Person> Persons {set;get;}
}
```

Now you can deserialize

```
var yourObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```